# Progressbar for long swing event dispatcher thread job

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a long running task (printing whole swing-frame 9999+ times). Unfortunately it runs well only in event dispatch thread. So i need to block gui. I want at least to show progress to user. My first naive attemp does not work:

```
// this allo happens IN event dispatch thread
for (int i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
    doLongEDTJob(i);
    myProgressBar.setValue(myProgressBar.getValue() + 1);
    myProgressBar.repaint();
}
```

What's wrong with that? Just nothing happens.

**upd**:
Here is example, that illustarates the problem:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final int max = 40000;
        final JPanel pp = new JPanel();
        final JProgressBar bb = new JProgressBar();
        bb.setMaximum(max);

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1920, 1080, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();

        JButton b = new JButton();
        b.setAction(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                    pp.paintComponents(g2);
                    bb.setValue(i);
                }
            }
        });

        b.setText("long EDT task");
        pp.add(bb);
        pp.add(b);
        frame.add(pp);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your [mcve]

Comment: ...................hello?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels added an example.

Comment: Paint your Swing components to a BufferedImage once.  Then, off the Event Dispatch thread, paint the BufferedImage 9,999 times.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc it would be a right option. But this is minimal example to show the problem. In my scenario refactor code to split swing and non-swing would require to much work and would make code more complicated. So i need something to work in EDT. I know this is not how it was designed.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately it runs well only in event dispatch thread. So i need to block gui. I want at least to show progress to user.

You've got conflicting requirements -- if you block the event thread with a long running process, this will block the event thread from painting and thus from updating the GUI --, and so you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you ask how to solve "X" when the solution is to use a different approach entirely.

The real solution to your problem is to figure out why you're not able to run the long-running task off of the EDT and then change the task so that it runs well **off** of the Swing event thread, and then once this is done, set the JProgressBar's value on the event thread, often best done using a SwingWorker. For a more detailed answer on just how to do this, you'll need to show and post more, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As i said: the nature of long task is painting swing components. Swing components can be painted correctly only in EDT by swing design. So using a standart approach with running long task not in EDT just does not work in this special case.